# Running nodes in different machine

Tags: corda

I tried as like given in readme document for running nodes on separate machines.
controller and nodeA got started in one machine.
but in another machine,only nodeB gets started .nodeC won’t.
And also not saying "node for party B " started like that.

Comment: Can you check nodeB's logs (under `nodeB/logs`) and see what error messages it gives? Does starting the node directly (going to the `nodeB` folder and running `java -jar corda.jar`) work? Is this on Windows or Mac?

Comment: am not starting the node directly. commonly starting all the nodes using runnodes.bat in command prompt. this is on Windows. eventhough nodes got started, am not getting the message like "Node for party B" started. is this affect the performance ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not getting the message"? Could you update the question with your terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a similar problem that was solved just by installing new JDK 8.

To run the node just do:

```
java -jar .\corda.jar
```

or use the bat file